# Matlab Simulink coder redefinition error

Tags: c, matlab, header-files, simulink, redefinition

I am trying to integrate a model that I designed in Simulink to work in my S-function (C-code). For this I used the Simulink Code generation (System target file: err.tlc) to build C-Code.

I am am doing it in this seemingly overly complex way because my main s-function is realizing a evolutionary algorithm and this Simulink model is how it evaluates each individual. (hope that makes sense).

So I just generated the C-code and am now trying to implement it in this S-function c-code.
As I am fairly new to this is used the generated ert_main.c as a reference.

```
#include <stdio.h>                     /* This ert_main.c example uses printf/fflush */
#include "Peltier_model.h"             /* Model's header file */
#include "rtwtypes.h"
#include "builtin_typeid_types.h"
#include "multiword_types.h"
#include "rt_logging.h"
#define QUOTE1(name)                   #name
#define QUOTE(name)                    QUOTE1(name)              /* need to expand name */
#ifndef SAVEFILE
# define MATFILE2(file)                #file ".mat"
# define MATFILE1(file)                MATFILE2(file)
# define MATFILE                       MATFILE1(MODEL)
#else
# define MATFILE                       QUOTE(SAVEFILE)
#endif
```

this part I copied to the header file of my own C-code.
When I trie to mex it I first had the problem that it could not find rt_logging.h, so I included the following path in mex:

```
   mex -I/Applications/MATLAB_R2013b.app/rtw/c/src ....
```

That solved that part.

The problem now is that my included Peltier_model.h (generated code) includes rt_logging.h which includes rt_mxclassid.h (all of which chi with Matlab and i didn't touch) which then creates a redefinition error:

```
In file included from Peltier_model_ert_rtw/Peltier_model.h:28:
In file included from /Applications/MATLAB_R2013b.app/rtw/c/src/rt_logging.h:19:
/Applications/MATLAB_R2013b.app/rtw/c/src/rt_mxclassid.h:18:2: error: redefinition of     enumerator 'mxLOGICAL_CLASS'
    mxLOGICAL_CLASS,
    ^
/Applications/MATLAB_R2013b.app/extern/include/matrix.h:287:5: note: previous definition is here
mxLOGICAL_CLASS,
^
```

So I have a problem with the redefinition of enumerates (from within rt_mxclassid.h) previously defined in matrix.h.

The same happens for the other enumerates defined in that part of the matrix.h

rt_classid.h:

```
/* $Revision: 1.1.6.1 $ */

#ifndef __rt_mxclassid_h__
#define __rt_mxclassid_h__

typedef enum {
mxUNKNOWN_CLASS = 0,
mxCELL_CLASS = 1,
mxSTRUCT_CLASS,
mxLOGICAL_CLASS,
mxCHAR_CLASS,
mxRESERVED5_CLASS, /* mxVOID_CLASS */
mxDOUBLE_CLASS,
mxSINGLE_CLASS,
mxINT8_CLASS,
mxUINT8_CLASS,
mxINT16_CLASS,
mxUINT16_CLASS,
mxINT32_CLASS,
mxUINT32_CLASS,
mxINT64_CLASS,      /* place holder - future enhancements */
mxUINT64_CLASS,     /* place holder - future enhancements */
mxRESERVED16_CLASS, /* mxFUNCTION_CLASS */
mxRESERVED17_CLASS, /* mxOPAQUE_CLASS */
mxOBJECT_CLASS
} mxClassID;

#endif /* __rt_mxclassid_h__ */
```

relevant part of matrix.h:

```
/**
 * Enumeration corresponding to all the valid mxArray types.
 */
typedef enum
{
mxUNKNOWN_CLASS = 0,
mxCELL_CLASS,
mxSTRUCT_CLASS,
mxLOGICAL_CLASS,
mxCHAR_CLASS,
mxVOID_CLASS,
mxDOUBLE_CLASS,
mxSINGLE_CLASS,
mxINT8_CLASS,
mxUINT8_CLASS,
mxINT16_CLASS,
mxUINT16_CLASS,
mxINT32_CLASS,
mxUINT32_CLASS,
mxINT64_CLASS,
mxUINT64_CLASS,
mxFUNCTION_CLASS,
mxOPAQUE_CLASS,
mxOBJECT_CLASS, /* keep the last real item in the list */
#if defined(_LP64) || defined(_WIN64)
mxINDEX_CLASS = mxUINT64_CLASS,
#else
mxINDEX_CLASS = mxUINT32_CLASS,
#endif
/* TEMPORARY AND NASTY HACK UNTIL mxSPARSE_CLASS IS COMPLETELY ELIMINATED */
mxSPARSE_CLASS = mxVOID_CLASS /* OBSOLETE! DO NOT USE */
}
mxClassID;
```

I am quite lost how to deal with this since any of the problematic files are written by me. Any Help would be much appreciated !!

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point but this seems a really convoluted way of doing things. If you want to integrate a Simulink model into another one, why not use model reference? That's precisely what it's designed to do. If you really must generate an S-function from your Simulink model, then include the generated S-function as a block in the top-level model, not as code within another S-function!!

Comment: Maybe I should have pointed out that the S-function is an evolutionary algorithm that iterates through a lot of simulations of this small simulink model. My thought was that integrating the model in this way would vastly improve performance. Also it would get messy with my sample times because for every Control output of my evolutionary algorithm s-function it has to check numerous parameter combination in order to find the best.

Comment: I just added that clarification to the initial question.  My question now is why including a matlab provided header file (rt_logging.h) results in this redefinition error....I am fairly lost with this... thanks for the help !

Comment: I got around it by disabling the Matlab signal logging for the code generation. The questionable header files are not used anymore. thx